# running a method continously using the thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a method which contains volley network library which will send some data to php server and fetch based on the value sent. I want to run this method continuously.  I have created a Thread in the Oncreate method like below.

```
new Thread(){

    @Override
     public void run(){
         second.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        getNumber(second.this.getContentResolver());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
 }.start();
```

But i am not sure whether it is working. how can i check it is working or any mistake is there on implementation?

Comment: Try to log the response you get from server.
But the code you have shown will not run `getNumber()` method continuously. It will be executed once and the thread will be stopped there after. If you want to do some operations that are continuously running in the background then I suggest you use `Service`.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: You can debug application and add breakpoint to getNumber() method.

Comment: @Piyush Yes sure. What is it?

Comment: I dont want to go for service, instead i used this. any better options?\

Comment: If you want to use this then there is an option but it might not be the best option. Add a `while loop` with `true` in condition. And your thread will be running constantly.
BTW did you get the answer of `how do I check if it's working or not' ?

Comment: Check the API with RestAPI applications like Postman, if they fetch the data correctly, then your application should probably too. It all depends on the parameters you pass to the API. Even if you send an invalid header, the API may work differently.

Comment: @Piyush let's discuss this in chat room. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129991/last-year-project-training